# Remove /index/ from Zend Paginator

Tags: php, zend-framework, pagination, friendly-url

i'm having a little trouble to remove 'index' from paginates url with Zend Paginator, here is my app.ini:

```
resources.router.routes.usuarios.route = /admin/usuarios/pagina/:pagina
resources.router.routes.usuarios.defaults.module = admin
resources.router.routes.usuarios.defaults.controller = usuarios
resources.router.routes.usuarios.defaults.action = index
resources.router.routes.usuarios.defaults.pagina = 1
```

But on the pagination page, the function:

```
<a href="<?= $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->next)); ?>">Próxima &gt;&gt;</a> |
```

Returns me /site/admin/usuarios/index/pagina/2, i need /site/admin/usuarios/pagina/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
<?php $this->url(array('controller'=> 'usuarios', 'action'=> 'index', 'module'=> 'admin', 'pagina' => $this->next)); ?>
```

or this

```
<?php $this->url(array('pagina' => $this->next), 'usuarios'); ?>
```